Hard ops smart apply menu is missing
I just started using Hard ops. But it seems there is no Smart Apply in my context menu. Does anyone know what am I missing? I tried to search for this issue but I can't find anything related.


I just had to switch to Object Mode. Then the Operations > Smart Apply option is displayed.
